# change the way select box and checkbox look in different browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

is there a way to display select box and checkbox the same way(default design) it is displayed in chrome using bootstrap.
I'm facing some design issues when it comes to cross browser especially in IE and safari
 there are some font and alignment difference

[image: this is from chrome]
[image: this is from firefox]

Comment: Those dropdown styles are set by the browser. You could of course build your own custom one or use a library or something. But the default dropdown style is set by the browser.

Comment: so i assume the same goes for check boxes and file upload field  also?

Comment: Correct. Unless you custom build it yourself the browser controls it.